# onClick event returning Every Modal instead of a Single Modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to build a Jeopardy like game using React and Redux. I currently have an onClick event set to each `li`, but whenever I click on it, I get every Modal to pop up instead of the one that is attached to that `li` item. I have my code separated in different files but I believe these two files are the only ones I need to show:

```
const ModalView = React.createClass({

  pass: function(){
    console.log('pass clicked');
    store.dispatch({type:"MODAL_TOGGLE"})
  },
  submit: function(){
    console.log('submit clicked');
    store.dispatch({type:"MODAL_TOGGLE"})

  },

  render: function(){
    let question = this.props.question
    let category = this.props.category
    let answer = this.props.answer
    let val = this.props.value

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="modal">
          <p>{category}</p>
          <p>{question}</p>
          <p>{answer}</p>
          <p>{val}</p>

          <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="type in your answer">
          </input>
          <button onClick={this.submit}>Submit</button>
          <button onClick={this.pass}>Pass</button>

        </div>
      </div>

    )
  }

})
```

and ValuesView

```
const ValuesView = React.createClass({
  modalPopUp: function(value){
    store.dispatch({type:"MODAL_TOGGLE"})
  },
  render: function(){
    let showClass = "show-content"
    let hideClass = "hide-content"
    if (this.props.modal){
      showClass = "hide-content"
      hideClass = "show-content"
    }
    return (<div>
      <ul className="list">
        {this.props.datum.clues.slice(0,5).map((data, i) => {
          if (data.value === null){
            return <div>
                    <div className={hideClass}>
                      <ModalView
                      category = {this.props.category}
                      question = {data.question}
                      answer = {data.answer}
                      value ={data.value} />
                    </div>
                    <li onClick={this.modalPopUp} key={i}>$600</li>
                  </div>
          }
          return   <div>
                    <div className={hideClass}>
                      <ModalView
                      category = {this.props.category}
                      question = {data.question}
                      answer = {data.answer}
                      value ={data.value}/>
                    </div>
                    <li
                    category = {this.props.category}
                    onClick={this.modalPopUp} key={i}>${data.value}</li>
                  </div>
        })}
      </ul>
        </div>
    )
  }
})
```

How would I go about only getting the corresponding Modal to display instead of every one? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to code real Modal I suggest you to use some already implemented component like https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal (I'm not saying is mandatory, nor even whit the example I suggest, could be other)

I think that `store.dispatch({type:"MODAL_TOGGLE"})` in some way toggle `modal` prop between `true` and `false`. Then you just use that flag to toggle a class to show or hide content I guess (I would need to see you css).

The problem with this approach is (apart that is not the best way to do this for many reasons) that you are using the same class for every item in your `clues` array.

In some way you need to store which is the "modal" you want to show, and then in the render, just apply the show class to this item.

Maybe:

```
const ValuesView = React.createClass({
  modalPopUp: function(index){
    return function (event) {
      store.dispatch({
        type:"MODAL_TOGGLE",
        payload: {
          modalIndex: index // Save modalIndex prop
        }
      })
    }
  },
  render: function(){
    return (<div>
      <ul className="list">
        {this.props.datum.clues.slice(0,5).map((data, i) => {
          if (data.value === null){
            return <div>
                    <div className={(this.prosp.modal && this.props.modalIndex === i) ? "show-content" : "hide-content"}>
                      <ModalView
                      category = {this.props.category}
                      question = {data.question}
                      answer = {data.answer}
                      value ={data.value} />
                    </div>
                    <li onClick={this.modalPopUp(i)} key={i}>$600</li>
                  </div>
          }
          return   <div>
                    <div className={(this.prosp.modal && this.props.modalIndex === i) ? "show-content" : "hide-content"}>
                      <ModalView
                      category = {this.props.category}
                      question = {data.question}
                      answer = {data.answer}
                      value ={data.value}/>
                    </div>
                    <li
                    category = {this.props.category}
                    onClick={this.modalPopUp(i)} key={i}>${data.value}</li>
                  </div>
        })}
      </ul>
        </div>
    )
  }
})
```